# Общие вопросы по c#

Tags: c#

1. Можем ли мы в интерфейсах создавать, что то вроде поля класса. Например мне нужно чтобы в интерфейсе был: `Mysqlconnection`. И я потом при наследовании переопределял его.
2. При работе с статическим полем класса создается объект или как? Например у меня часто такое встречается такой вариант развития событий. Мне нужно из 1 формы например формы авторизации передать значение из текстового поля в другую форму. Я создаю `static string Login=...`. И потом в 2 форме где надо это значение получить, я обращаюсь например к классу `Form1` таким образом `string getLogin=Form1.Login`
3. Я хочу сделать класс который будет иметь, например шаблон для заполнения всех параметров соединения MYSQL и потом его использовать в другом классе. Но, статические поля не действуют на классы. Я думал изначально сделать через Interface, но они не работали. Дабы уменьшить количество кода и распределить по функциям его. Даже примерный код скинуть не могу, ибо делал давно и прогу сделал через костыли и получилось в общем не красиво, поэтому сейчас хочу делать все по уму. Если можно скиньте хоть самый примитивный пример.

Comment: Придерживайтесь пожалуйста принципа "одна тема - один вопрос". На текущий момент проголосовал за закрытие вопроса как слишком общего.

Comment: Вы неправильно реализуете логику, поэтому у вас проблемы. Я бы на вашем месте, если так хочется, создал бы класс который имел бы свойства которые нужно изменять, и свойство, только get, которое создавало бы нужное подключение. И не нужно ни каких статических классов вообще.

Comment: @Monomax то есть все таки лучше в интерфейсе определить эти поля. Потом унаследовать и заполнить их. Так? Я к тому что у каждого будет свои данные для соединения с бд а переопределять глупо я считаю. Поэтому лучше создать класс и загрузить необходимые данные

Comment: @GnomSkull вам уже сказано про интерфейс. То что вы хотите не получится, это можно сделать через класс. Максимум в интерфейс вы можете вынести свойства. Но если у вас будет реализовывать логику всего один класс, то думать надо о другом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Поля в интерфейсах создавать нельзя. Свойства - можно.
2. В таком варианте, как Вы описали, объект создается только один раз, при первом обращении к типу. Дальше он хранится в памяти.
3. Вопрос не понятен, особенно "статические поля не действуют на классы".

Comment: Например у нас есть 2 класса. первый класс имеет например статическое поле типа mysqlconnection, и еще несколько статических полей. Затем для этого класса мы их определяем какими то значениями. И теперь я хочу например брать данные разными классами из этого класса. Но чтобы много раз не создавать объект класса, я хочу получать данные из уже готового. Объяснил как смог

Comment: @GnomSkull, Вам скорее всего нужно не статические свойства/поля использовать. Загуглите агрегацию в контексте ООП.